# Windows Scripting

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, active-directory

How to pull the users list from AD with only one read permission account by using a script.?
also I want to Create a script which allows in AD to create 10 OU's and 50 users in each OU.

Please suggest the suitable scripts.

Thanks
Crew.

Answer (score 1):

The Technet Scripting Center is your friend.

Here for Active Directory searching: [clicky](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=activedirectory&f%5B0%5D.Text=Active%20Directory&f%5B1%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=searching&f%5B1%5D.Text=Searching%20Active%20Directory), and here for other AD scripts: [clicky](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd793613.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using powershell with the Quest ActiveRoles cmdlets are the easiest way to get quickly up and running with script-based AD-related operations. It is well-documented and has a very broad user base = lots of google-able resources.
http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the script to do that exactly (10 OUs and 50 Users in each OU) or do you want to be able to decide how many OUs are created and how many users are created in the OUs when you run the script? Do you have a list of OUs and Users in a file or will you be entering them manually?

Answer (score 0):

I second Trondh's recommendation of PowerShell with the Quest ActiveRoles cmdlets add-on. I've had great success in incorporating the ActiveRoles cmdlets with custom user provisioning scripts.

Familiarizing yourself with the ActiveRoles cmdlets helps a great deal in day to day AD administration as well. Well worth the time to learn the basics.

Quite easy to pick up if you're already somewhat familiar with PowerShell as everything is well documented.